# Filter_SelectionChanged using a web service

Tags: c#, windows-8, async-await

When the search capability of a Windows8 app essentially delegates to a web service, one might expect to use code like this

```
var jsonresult = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(REQ);
```

then parsing the string to populate the result collection prior to assigning it to this.DefaultViewModel["Results"], but the await operator can only be used within an async method.

How is one expected to handle the scenario of searching by querying a web service?

I've tried moving the above code out into an async method

```
async void QueryWebservice(string queryText) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was merely the way the results are marshaled into the display elements. The viewmodel is an Observable. You have to populate the result collection *before* you assign it to this.DefaultViewModel["Results"]

The odd and erratic errors I was getting when I assigned the collection object and then populated it were a consequence of the fact that the framework was trying to populate the UI while I was modifying the collection from which it was obtaining values. When you do it the other way round, no problems occur.

Using an async method to query a web service works very well.